# Search in PHP array with a custom comparator

Tags: php, search

This is probably hopeless but still, is there a way to search for elements in an array with my own comparator function? Implementing it in PHP would result in slow searches, so maybe a better solution exists?

What I actually want from the search is a) get to know whether the element is present in the array and b) preferably, get the key (index) of the found element.

For example

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

and if the comparator would look like this

```
$comp = function ($arrValue, $findValue) {
    return ($arrValue % $findValue) == 0;
};
```

Then the comparator-based search function would return `true` if `8` was searched and, which would be nice of it, output the index of the found element, which is `7`.

Comment: Look at using `array_filter()`... but perhaps a few more details about what you want to actually do would help get you a more detailed answer

Comment: Yep, it's [`array_filter()`](http://us2.php.net//manual/en/function.array-filter.php) (it might not be appreciably faster than just writing a loop though)

Comment: @MarkBaker You're a couple seconds ahead of me on every comment this morning.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - just the luck of the draw

Comment: You can also use array_walk();

Comment: @MarkBaker a) get to know whether the element is present in the array and b) preferably, get the key (index) of the found element

Comment: @DesmondHume - a specific example of an array, the search criteria and the expected result might help; but your comment still points toward using array_filter() which maintains keys

Comment: I think array_search() might be a good option for this. array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful.

Comment: *"Implementing it in PHP would result in slow searches, so maybe a better solution exists?"* -- Well, you are obviously going to have to implement the comparison in PHP. And what's worse, if you do it as a standalone function you will get hit by the sadly bad PHP function call performance. If performance is your goal I would be surprised if anything other than a custom `foreach` came up on top.

Comment: @Jon You might be just about right, would still need an alternative non-`foreach` to run tests against.

Comment: Your example doesn't really need any kind of custom comparator: a simple array_search() will do the job

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
$findValue = 8;

$result = array_filter(
    $arr, 
    function ($arrValue) use($findValue) {
        return ($arrValue % $findValue) == 0;
    }
);
```

**EDIT**

Perhaps you mean something more like:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
$findValue = 3;

foreach(array_filter(
    $arr, 
    function ($arrValue) use($findValue) {
        return ($arrValue % $findValue) == 0;
    }
) as $key => $value) {
    echo $value, ' is a multiple of ', $findValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

**EDIT #2**

Or do you mean something a lot more sophisticated like:

```
function filter($values, $function) {
    return array_filter(
        $values,
        $function
    );
}

$isEven = function ($value) {
    return !($value & 1);
};

$isOdd = function ($value) {
    return $value & 1;
};

$data = range(1,10);

echo 'array_filter() for Odds', PHP_EOL;
var_dump(
    filter(
        $data,
        $isOdd
    )
);

echo 'array_filter() for Evens', PHP_EOL;
var_dump(
    filter(
        $data,
        $isEven
    )
);
```

or using PHP 5.5 Generators as well:

```
$isEven = function ($value) {
    return !($value & 1);
};

$isOdd = function ($value) {
    return $value & 1;
};

function xFilter(callable $callback, $args=array()) {
    foreach($args as $arg) {
        if (call_user_func($callback, $arg)) {
            yield $arg;
        }
    }
}

echo 'xFilter for Odds', PHP_EOL;
foreach(xFilter($isOdd, range(1,10)) as $i) {
    echo('num is: '.$i.PHP_EOL);
}

echo 'xFilter for Evens', PHP_EOL;
foreach(xFilter($isEven, range(1,10)) as $i) {
    echo('num is: '.$i.PHP_EOL);
}
```

Comment: Yes somewhere along these lines. I've just tested this approach to compare it with the trivial `foreach` solution, and `foreach` turned out to be faster..

Comment: Foreach will be faster, the difference is that callbacks provde a lot more flexibility

Comment: @MarkBaker I can make foreach use callback in my search function, can't I?

Comment: I see, nice one Mark.

Comment: I don't know how you can make foreach() use a callback, I'm really having great difficulty understanding what you're asking here... foreach() simply executes a block of code between its { and }

Comment: I think all he wants is to search an array for a key with a given value and he might be complicating things with callbacks. This is my interpretation from his post. :)

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry for that. What I meant was crafting my own function to run searches on arrays, put a `foreach` into it, and use `call_user_func` to call the comparator on each element until the searched element is found. The problem is, it's damn slow too.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks a lot, subject closed

Answer (score -4):

### http://ideone.com/DSfppl

I think an `array_search()` is what you're looking for. array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful. I think this resonates with what you are trying to achieve in your original question a) and b).

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

//finds if the value exist and returns key
$key = array_search(8, $array); 

//return key
echo $key;  //returns 7
```

Performance:

Array search is O(n).